# How to make Bootstrap Fixed Body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Now am using Bootstrap # for an Web Application.
My Application should be Same as in [REQUIREMENT](http://bologna.bakeca.it/)
Since am Applied Bootstrap, when i shrink the screen it shows as Responsive, But I really NOT NEEDED.

I need the Sticky Body Content. As Same in [NEEDED DEMO](http://bologna.bakeca.it/)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I not understand your question correctly. but you are going to make your website become not Responsive? Then one of the solution that I can suggest to you is to overwrite or reset some bootstrap.css function with your custom css, especially 
`@media (min-width:somepx){width:your_desired px}` with your own liking.

for example this bootstrap css default will define the container responsive size to 750px in case the screen is 768px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
```

for more information, you can read the information from the [bootstrap link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Comment: Yes Zuzu Softman..! Ur Understanding is correct, But when i override the property means when i resize the screen the Problem again happens.!

Comment: you have some demo of what have you done? what kind of problem that you faced when you try to resize the screen again?